# lm() for regression in R using for loop

Tags: r, regression, lm

I'm using lm() to do linear regression using two matrices (one data and one weights) where I'm looping through the columns and doing the regression using one column at a time. My data (e) is a 102 x 200,000 matrix, and looks like:

```
V1 V2 V3 ...
-0.79 -0.79 -0.79 ...
-0.93 -0.93 -0.93 ...
-0.18 -0.18 -0.18 ...
```

And my weights matrix (weights) is equal in dimensions. My design matrix (mod.our) is 102 x 29 and looks like:

```
X-intercept GI Hematopoietic Brain ...
1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
```

My code is:

```
lm.i<-c()
for (i in seq(1,216063,1)){
lm.i<-c(lm.i,lm(formula=e[,i] ~ mod.our, weights=weights[,i]))
}
```

Problem is it's been running for over 24 hours. Does anyone know how to do this faster? Or a better way in general?

Comment: Linear regression only fits slope plus constant, or NVAR + 1, or 103 coefficents in your problem.  The minimum number of rows you need is 206. You could sample the data rows randomly, and select 1000 of them, which reduce the size of the problem and may speed it up.

Comment: don't grow your list of results as you go by appending: pre-allocate it.  It would also be easy to distribute/parallelize the problem.

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, do you mean parallelize by using one for loop for say 1000 columns at a time (instead of the full 216,000)?

Comment: It's more efficient to use `lm.wfit` (which is the fitting function `lm` calls if weights are specified). And of course follow Ben Bolker's advise (preferably by using `lapply` or one of its parallel versions).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an iterative procedure to get the coefficients. I believe most commonly [Stochastic Gradient Descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) is used.

Someone shows an annotated example here:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/regression-via-gradient-descent-in-r/

Also, the package RSofia contains a SGD implementation in R. Or just google for such an application in your favorite R package.

I've personally only used SGD in Python (it would be my general suggestion to use Python for large machine learning problems, rather than R for speed purposes).